# How to extrapolate checkbox values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Not sure "extraploate" is the correct word, but anyway...

I have 2 groups of check boxes. I'd like to get the values from each group and then pair them with the other group so that every value selected corresponds to a pairing.

So for example:

```
Group 1
[x] 1
[x] 2
[x] 3

Group 2
[x] a
[x] b
[x] c
```

I'd like to take those checked values and return 9 pairs:
1a, 1b, 1c, 2a, 2b, 2c, 3a, 3b, 3c

Help?

Comment: Don't you mean radio buttons? With checkboxes, all of them could be checked at once.

Comment: Can you please add your actual HTML to the question.

Comment: And your javascript, since you've tagged it as a javacript question, we can assume you're trying to do this with javascript, correct?

Comment: HTML is just standard check boxes: <input type="checkbox" name="group1" value="1" />

Comment: And, no, I don't mean radio buttons... I mean check boxes... I need the ability for all to be checked at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/pMD5v/)***

Select the two groups and filter them to ensure you are only comparing the checked boxes. Then iterate the first group, and nest iterating the second group inside. Push the concatenated values to an array and then join it using to get the string desired.

```
var group1 = $('.group1')
  .find('input[type=checkbox]')
  .filter(function(){ return this.checked; });
var group2 = $('.group2')
  .find('input[type=checkbox]')
  .filter(function(){ return this.checked; });
var pairs = []; 
group1.each(function(){
 var me = this;
 group2.each(function(){
    pairs.push(me.value+this.value);
 });
});
var resultString = pairs.join(',');
```